# Using Jenkins, how would I create an SVN tag from a job's workspace?

Tags: jenkins

I normally check out code to a temp folder and run composer against the folder. If it passes, I then create a tag from within said folder. In Jenkins I can kick off composer just fine, but I need Jenkins to create the tag from the workspace and not from the branch.

If this can't be done using tagging feature within Jenkins, I suppose I could use a series of Post-Build scripts.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option on Jenkins to tag a particular build, which captures the workspace at that point in time.

Using the GUI, it's the `Tag this build` option which appears when viewing a  build.

Using a URL, it's

```
http://my-server:portnumber/jenkins/job/my_job_name/buildnumber/tagBuild/
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Does this allow me to tag it automatically once I run my build tasks? I need the whole process to be automated since I'm triggering the job remotely.

Comment: Ah I see. I think you may want the *Publish to Subversion repository* task, available as part of the job configuration - see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SVN+Publisher. I have not used this task myself, so I can't advise you any further than that.